# Does CouchDB need to be hosted along with my website, or am I going to work with it as a local server on my network or computer?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I'm learning the concepts of a NoSQL database, especially CouchDB. But I have a doubt that may sound stupid, but I have not found answers on the internet. Where does CouchDB work? On a regular web hosting service or on my local network? Ex: My computer and my localhost.

Comment: What is a "regular web hosting service" to you?

Comment: My language is not English, so I may not express myself so well with the online translator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CouchDB can be installed as [single-node](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/single-node.html) on any computer, including your local machine. CouchDB may also be used in [clustered mode](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/cluster.html).

[HTTP](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/basics.html#api-basics) is used to write data (documents) and request information from the database. Therefore, the database may be hosted along with your website but it doesn't have to. All depends on your use case. The only important thing is that your web application knows about the host name, port number and credentials allowing it to access CouchDB over HTTP.